# Identification of brown film inside a plastic water bottle

Tags: species-identification

What could this film be at the base of a plastic water bottle?

[image]

Also observed one around the neck.

[image]

Comment: May be water sediment or algae or cyanobacteria. Was they inside the bottle or outside the bottle?  Is it possible to you to see them in a microscope?

Comment: `Is it possible to you to see them in a microscope?`-No.They were inside.

Comment: I meant if a microscope is accessible to you (institute/ home). In the inner  wet portions algae may germinate. If unused, the bottle could be cut and the inner material could be scrapped, smeared and viewed under microscope.

Comment: I did understand what you said. No, it is not possible to view the film under microscope.

Comment: It could be algae or bacteria film, but also ironoxide.